# Meteor 1.3 crashes with TypeError after being updated

Tags: meteor

I received an email confirming a new meteor update, so I executed the following command

> meteor update

Now everytime I try to run my app this error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'displayName' of undefined
  at SourceProcessorSet.addLegacyHandler (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:151:84)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:187:14
  at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
  at SourceProcessorSet.merge (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\build-plugin.js:181:7)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:377:26
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:373:26
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:367:18
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:360:34
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:358:23
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at Object.enterJob (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:332:26)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:370:16
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:175:26
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.compile (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\compiler.js:170:5)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2601:24
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:279:13
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:272:29
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:270:18
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:261:23
  at [object Object].withValue (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:107:14)
  at Object.capture (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:260:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2546:31)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\runners\run-app.js:651:36
  at Function.run (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\tool-env\profile.js:485:12)
  at bundleApp (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\runners\run-app.js:641:34)
  at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\runners\run-app.js:694:35)
  at AppRunner._fiber (C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\runners\run-app.js:957:28)
  at C:\Users\howna13\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\runners\run-app.js:472:12
```

I tried running

> meteor npm install --save classnames

However, the error keeps appearing. Any idea of what the problem might be and how to be solved?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @Kyll My code worked well before the update, that's why I think it have to be something related with the update

Comment: Well, unless it's an extremely common issue with the update (which it may well be seeing all the recent issues and questions about it), there's isn't much we can do to try and reproduce it on our own machines to diagnose your issue and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more code for us to help you out. At first glance, you seem to have converted your React components to classes and kept the displayName property.

You should remove displayName from React ES6 components definition.

I don't think classnames will get you in any trouble.

```
npm i --save classnames
```

And when you want to use it:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
```

Remember to keep imports at the to of the file.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your time. The project I'm working on is confidential. I would share the part of the code that is suspitious to be failing but as everything was behaving well before the meteor update I don't know which part of the project code share.

Comment: Has it been fixed?